# MongoDb schema validation outer object optional but inner object is required

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've a MongoDb model

```
optionalRoot: {
        optionalA: {
          requiredForA1: { type: String, required: true },
          requiredForA1: { type: String, required: true }
        },
        optionalB: {
          requiredForB1: { type: String, required: true },
          requiredForB1: { type: String, required: true }
        },
}
```

Is it even possible to express this in schema? Essentially `optionalA` and `optionalB` may or may not exist, but if they do, they should contain `requiredFor*` for each

Answer (score 1):

what I would do in your case is to break the schema in three collections. It would be something like this:

```
OptionalRoot: {
   optionalA: [optionalAId],
   optionalB: [optionalBId]
}

OptionalA: {
    requiredForA1: {type: String, required: true}
    requiredForA2: {type: Number, required: true}
}

OptionalB : {
    requiredForB1: {type: String, required: true}
    requiredForB2: {type: Date, required: true}
}
```

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: While this will work, but I've a large collection of unique `Optional` objects, so this will lead to explosion of collections in database and would unnecessarily complicate the lookup.